# Is it possible to declare an optional and unique attribute for a class model in (Flask) SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I just need to declare an attribute that is unique and optional. Is it possible in Python Sql Alchemy using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy?

membership_number = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

Comment: "unique and optional" is a contradiction.. probably you mean unique and accepting empty value as one of the unique values it has. Btw unique is achieved using indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a primary key you can define it just as a `primary_key`:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    membership_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

But if you need it to be unique apart from the primary_key use a `UniqueContraint`

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    membership_id = db.Column(db.String)

    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('membership_id'),)
```

or

```
    membership_id = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
```

Comment: or you could just also add unique.                                     email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)